# How to use quotation marks and full stops in Python function argument

Tags: python, function, format, arguments

I can't seem to get this formatting working in Python. I am trying to define a function that holds an argument on the form - "[Some].[Name]"

Can anyone tell me how I can this working? I think I have tried all combinations of ' and ", but regardless both the [.] and ["] in the argument seems to not work.

In the below code I am trying to define the argument as "VWS.co"

```
def get_stock_data(Company):
    #This function defines the data to be collected.
    #send a get request to query Company's end of day stock prices in period
    global VWS_data
    Stock_data = yf.Ticker(Company)
    Stock_data = Stock_data.history(period="5y")
    # look at the first 5 rows of the dataframe
    print(Stock_data)
    print(Stock_data.describe(include='all'))

get_stock_data("VWS.co")
```

**Edit**:
Using escape characters get_stock_data(""VWS.co"") got the definition working. However, something is still wrong. When I run the script it still only works using "VWS.co" as the definition. See below code, the VWS_data_with_arg works. VWS_data does not. Am i missing something really obvious here?

```
def get_stock_data(Company):
    Stock_data = yf.Ticker("VWS.co")
    Stock_data_with_arg = yf.Ticker(Company)
    VWS_data = Stock_data.history(period="5y")
    VWS_data_with_arg = Stock_data_with_arg.history(period="5y")
    print(VWS_data) #This returns the expected values
    print(VWS_data_with_arg) #This returns an empty dataset

get_stock_data("\"VWS.co\"")
```

Comment: `get_stock_data('"VWS.co"')` will do you!

Answer (score 0):

You should use escape characters.

```
get_stock_data("\"VWS.co\"")
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved what i thought was the issue. However, it is still not working.

When I remove the argument and insert "VMS.co" in the statement, it works.
However, when I use escape characters it fails to define VMS_data, I did try to print Company and it was defined as expected.

I also added the statement "global VWS_data" at the top of the function, still without luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use raw strings

```py
get_stock_data(r'"VWS.co"')
```

Comment: There's nothing in the string that requires a raw string literal. `'"VWS.co"'` produces the same value.